# How to format DateTime to short format in GridView column?

Tags: asp.net

I have a DateTime column in my Gridview (asp.net webapplication) and I want to show only the date part.
Is there a DataformatString that will give me output like '2023.07.27'?
I tried

```
DataFormatString="{0:yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

but it still shows the time part.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: lets see abit more of your code(gridview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted DataFormatString looks correct.

This suggests that your data source column here is not a DateTime column from SQL server. Or at some point in the SQL view, or data source, the datetime column is (or has) been converted to a string.

If "some how" that datetime column been changed into a string?

Then you could try converting it back to a date time, and then format that datetime.

You would have to drop the BoundField from the GridView, and then adopt a templated column, such as:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblBook" runat="server"
            Text='<%# 
            Eval("BookingDate").ToString() == ""  
            ? "" 
            : Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("BookingDate")).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")  
            %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

However, better would be to fix the data source in question. I would double check that column, since if you are feeding the GridView a DateTime column, then your posted formatting example should work.

Perhaps you provide additional code and markup, since at this point in time we don’t have sufficient information here.

Comment: thanks. I found an error causing this behavour - the date on the way to the GridView  was converted to a String, so then it could be formatted using DataFormatString. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: All good then! - and bonus points is that you had the correct format in the first place!